# how do i can stretch my div according text?

Tags: css, html, height, stretch

how do i can stretch my div according text

I want to stretch height of a div , with the text user posted

look at the screen shot its clear.

CSS :

```
.cmnt{ width: 570px; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; float: right; margin-right:     15px; clear:both; }
.cmnt .body{ width: 570px; background: #333333; min-height: 90px; height: auto; }
.cmnt .text{ width: 513px; float: left; font-family: arial; color: #FFF; }
.cmnt .arrow{ width: 570px; height: 7px; background: url(../img/comment_arr.jpg) no-repeat     17px top; }
.cmnt .info{ width: 470px; height: 20px; font-family: arial; font-size: 14px; color: #FFF; float: left; text-align: left; }
```

HTML :

```
<div class="cmnt">
<a name="comment-id" />
<div class="body">
<div class="text">
text<br/>
text<br/>
text<br/>
text<br/>
text<br/>
text<br/>
text<br/>
</div>
<img class="avatar" src="assets/img/cmnt-u.jpg" align="absmiddle" />
</div>
<div class="arrow"></div>
<div class="info">
&nbsp;&nbsp;smith (date)
</div>
<div class="rp">
<a href="#comment">reply ↓</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Image

[image: Comment Image => [comment view][1]]

Parent :

```
<div class="comment">
<div class="cmntHeader">Comments</div>
<div class="cmntBody">
<center>
....
</center>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding a `float: left` CSS property to your **outer** container.

```
.cmnt .body{ float: left; width: 570px; background: #333333; min-height: 90px; height: auto; }
```

**Here's a fiddle for you**

http://jsfiddle.net/znQa8/

Hope it helps.

Comment: how will that help adjusting the height?

Comment: I've updated my post. Outer container is what I meant, and desired result is there. @Vogel612, try improving your CSS knowledge by constant learning and improving yourself.

Comment: @semir.babjic sure i ain't got nothing else to do ;)) right now i am too much in work with asp.net and php so i can't spare too much time, but ofc you are right

Answer (score 1):

The height of a container is automatically adjusted, if not specified, according to the child (not floated) elements.
Because the div (class=text) is floated, its height doesn't take into account. Whenever you used a float, systematically try to clear it after to resolve the height problem.

```
<div class="text">
...
</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

it could be a possibility to add:

```
div.body
{
height: auto;
}
```

but i'm not sure it isn't killing the whole layout

In reference to My Head Hurts you need to clear your floats:

```
.cmnt .body
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This is the default state for a div, since there is no height declaration it's already there.

Comment: hmmm. sure it doesn't get overridden by a parent-property, where the height is defined in total?

Answer (score 0):

`min-height` would be your solution.

Comment: nope. you just define a minimum height that already exists, given by the image+ padding...

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is that you have a floating container with floating children.

In this case, the floating container "ignores" the children dimensions. This is probably a side effect of the implementation of the real primary objective of float (that was to have floating images on wrapped text).

In this article you can see the floating purpose and a list of workarrounds:
http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/59

And this is what I think is the best solution so far, the micro clearfix (best about it is that you can put in you css and reuse it whenever you need it again):
http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Just add this css block to your css file:

```
/*THE CLEARFIX HACK*/
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { *zoom: 1; }
```

And then add the clearfix class to the "body" div.

jsfiddle: XZRH5